# Community Sharing set field mapping

Tags: community, sharing, apex-sharing, sharing-sets

I am trying to work with Community sets and I am facing the following issues. I had created some sharing `User:Contact = Case:Parent.Some_Lookup_Field__c` and records were successfully shared

I changed Case OWD from Private to Public Read Write as a result of which the Sharing sets got deleted. But now that I have reverted the OWDs back to Private and have redone my sets with the above permissions, records are still not being shared anymore.

Also, I would like to understand the difference had I written

User:Contact = Case:Some_Lookup_Field__c instead

Comment: I'm just curious, when you say "records are still not being shared anymore" are you talking about existing records or have you tried creating a new record to see if the new one is shared? My thought is that the older records created before you switched it back to private may not be shared but new ones may be. If that is the case, you may have to do some back fill to insert case shares to re-share existing cases.

Comment: @gNerb I meant the existing records. I am trying to understand here, why won't the old records be shared any more? Previously, Sharing was private. Some existing records were shared. I switched it. Sharing sets got deleted. Then I reverted it to private. However, the records which were being shared before are not visible anymore. Is there any sharing recalculation that I can do? (like we do for sharing settings)

Comment: If it is the same sharing set criteria, it shall work the same. Check if the sharing calculation (from public to private) is still running at background jobs and also verify that the assigned profiles are the same. User:Contact = Case:Some_Lookup_Field__c will works differently for User:Contact = Case:Parent.Some_Lookup_Field__c. User:Contact = Case:Some_Lookup_Field__c will share all the cases where Some_Lookup_Field__c is the contact associated to logged in community user